# PyTorch C++ - how to know the recommended version of cuDNN?

Tags: pytorch

I've previously inferenced `TensorFlow` graphs from C++.  Now I'm embarking on working out how to inference `PyTorch` graphs via C++.

My first question is, how can I know the recommended version of `cuDNN` to use with `LibTorch`, or if I'm doing my own PyTorch compile?

Determining the recommended CUDA version is easy.  Upon going to https://pytorch.org/ and choosing the options under `Quick Start Locally` (`PyTorch Build`, `Your OS`, etc.) the site makes it pretty clear that CUDA 10.1 is recommended, but there is no mention of cuDNN version and upon Googling I'm unable to find a definitive answer for this.

From what I understand about PyTorch on ubuntu, if you use the Python version you have to install the CUDA driver (ex. so `nvidia-smi` works, version `440` currently), but the CUDA and cuDNN install are not actually required beyond the driver because they are included in the pip3 package, is this correct?  If so, then is there a command I can run in a Python script that shows the version of CUDA (expected to be 10.1) and cuDNN that the pip pre-compiled .whl uses?  I suspect there is such a command but I'm not familiar enough with PyTorch yet to know what that may be or how to look it up.

I've ran into compile and inferencing errors using C++ with TensorFlow when I was not using the specific recommended version of cuDNN for a certain version of TensorFlow and CUDA so I'm aware these version can be sensitive and I have to make the right choices from the get-go.  If anybody can assist in determining the recommended version of cuDNN for a certain version of PyTorch that would be great.

Comment: AFAIK it's usually `cuDNN` `7.0` od `7.5`, you might check their provided docker images [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/pytorch/pytorch/tags), it's ad-hoc but maybe will help in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the info and suggestion.  That docker container has cuDNN 7.6.5.32, but until I'm able to verify a successful PyTorch compile or C++ inference I'm not convinced by that source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUDA is supported via the graphics card driver, AFAIK there's no separate "CUDA driver". The system graphics card driver pretty much just needs to be new enough to support the CUDA/cudNN versions for the selected PyTorch version. To the best of my knowledge backwards compatibility is included in most drivers. For example a driver that supports CUDA 10.1 (reported via nvidia-smi) will also likely support CUDA 8, 9, 10.0

If you installed with pip or conda then a version of CUDA and cudNN are included with the install. You can query the actual versions being used in python with `torch.version.cuda` and `torch.backends.cudnn.version()`.

Comment: With a pip3 install of torch 1.4.0 and torchvision 0.5.0, the python statement "torch.backends.cudnn.version()" shows a result of "7603".  What does this mean?  7.6.3.x ?? or 7.6.0.3x ?? or something different ??

Comment: According to the [code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c83f9849067c5f14ce8e61f84b62af1215af5133/torch/backends/cudnn/__init__.py#L58) `# cuDNN version is MAJOR*1000 + MINOR*100 + PATCH` so I think you should read as 7.6.3. The fourth number can be more than two digits so this 4 digit version format wouldn't support that so it must be 7.6.3.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I asked in the PyTorch forum also to be 100% sure: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-backends-cudnn-version-what-does-the-output-mean/68361

Comment: I'm having trouble tracking down the meaning of the patch sub-version but if Nvidia uses a sane versioning system then it should be fully inter-compatible with others as long as major, minor, and patch versions match.